# sendgrid php library get emails into quoted coma separated values

Tags: php, pdo, sendgrid

I've been stuck on this for a few days now. Sendgrid needs the values double quoted and coma separated.  When I print out `$emaildata`, I get the values in the required format. I also get a success message when I run the script, but no emails are being sent. I've tried the same with `curl` but it's the same result. I have a feeling it's the way I'm fetching data that's the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Get List Data from form, several lists can be selected

$lists = $_POST['lists_array'];

$values = array_map('array_pop', $lists);
$imploded = implode(',', $values);

// Query the database for the selected lists
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE list_name = '$imploded'");                      
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Select all email ids from the given lists
$edata= array_column($rows, 'subscriber_email');

// Put email ids into quoted, coma seperated format.
$emaildata = '"'.implode('", "', $edata).'"';


// SendGrid PHP Library 

require("sendgrid-php.php");


/* USER CREDENTIALS   
====================================================*/
$sg_username = "XXXX";
$sg_password = "XXXX";


/* CREATE THE SENDGRID MAIL OBJECT
====================================================*/
$sendgrid = new SendGrid( $sg_username, $sg_password );
$mail = new SendGrid\Email();



/* SMTP API
====================================================*/
// ADD THE RECIPIENTS
$emails = array (
   $emaildata
);
$mail->setSmtpapiTos($emails);


/* SEND MAIL    
====================================================*/
try {
    $mail->
    setFrom( "$fromemail" )->
    setSubject( "$subjectline" )->
    setText( "$previewmessage" )->
    setHtml( "$campaign_html" );
    $sendgrid->send( $mail );

    echo "Success";
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "Unable to send mail: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've got this sorted. Instead of the headache of supplying coma separated values like in their example, were just gonna store the data in an array. We then pass this on to sendgrid. We can pass up to 10k emails.

`$storeArray[] =  $row['subscriber_email'];`

And then pass this array on to sendgrid like so

`$emails = $storeArray;
 $mail->setSmtpapiTos($emails);`

So the final code looks like this. I'm sure there are other ways to do this but in case anyone needs a working example you can use the below. I hope someone finds this useful :)

```
// Get List Data from form, several lists can be selected

$lists = $_POST['filter_array'];

$values = array_map('array_pop', $lists);
$imploded = implode(',', $values);

// Query the database for the selected lists
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE subscriberlist_id IN ($imploded) AND subscriber_status='enabled'");                      
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
$storeArray[] =  $row['subscriber_email']; // Put email ids into an array.
}




// SendGrid PHP Library 


require("sendgrid-php.php");


/* USER CREDENTIALS
/  Fill in the variables below with your SendGrid
/  username and password.
====================================================*/
$sg_username = "XXXX";
$sg_password = "XXXX";


/* CREATE THE SENDGRID MAIL OBJECT
====================================================*/
$sendgrid = new SendGrid( $sg_username, $sg_password );
$mail = new SendGrid\Email();



/* SMTP API
====================================================*/
// ADD THE RECIPIENTS

$emails = $storeArray; // Passing the array of email ids.
$mail->setSmtpapiTos($emails);



/* SEND MAIL
====================================================*/
try {
    $mail->
    setFrom( "$fromemail" )->
    setSubject( "$subjectline" )->
    setText( "$previewmessage" )->
    setHtml( "$campaign_html" );
    $sendgrid->send( $mail );   

    echo "Success";

} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    echo "Unable to send mail: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```